# design CPM- PERT graphs using html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, graph

I need to design a PERT kind of graph (something like graph theory with nodes and edges but time dependent). This graph needs to be dynamic as it will take some data from server on regular basis and compute and display results. There is a particular time till which the task should be done and i need to show the progress of the work done as well. And i am told to do this using HTML5 and JavaScript..HELP!!

Comment: Have you found any solution? Could you please share with us. We are also facing same issue.

Comment: its a pretty complicated  used. But i used jquery for it.!

Comment: Have you used any third party library as well ?